# How do i show progress of a loop in a specific column - DataGridView?

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, datagridview

I am looping 10000 times and i want to show my loop progress in a specific column.

```
for(int i = 0; i< 10000; data++)
{
     // Do something...
}
```

Comment: Which data source are you using? DataTabel or List of entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To place data inside the Datagrid.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a list of entities, You could do something like this:

```
public class DataItem 
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public int ProgressInPercent { get; set; }
}

...
List<DataItem> dataSource = new List<DataItem> 
{
  new DataItem { ID = 1, Title = "Title 1", ProgressInPercent = 0}
};

dataGridView.DataSource = dataSource;
for(int data = 0; data < 1000000; data++)
{
   dataSource[0].ProgressInPercent = data * 100 / 1000000;
}
```